# How to automatically hide an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My android application uses 
 `AlertDialog.Builder.setMessage("OK").show();`
but this panel is not automatically hidden. The user must click the return key on their phone.
How can I display a message for three seconds, then automatically hide it?

Answer (score 1):

use message handler to hide your dialog box. try this..

```
AlertDialog test_ok = null;
android.os.Handler messagHandler = null;
Message msg = new Message();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    test_ok = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("ok").create();
    test_ok.show();

    messagHandler = new android.os.Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 1:
                    test_ok.dismiss();
                    break;
            }
        };
    };

    msg.what = 1;
    messagHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 4000);
}
```

Comment: make sure to test is test_ok is still shown before dismissing it, otherwise it will crash

Answer (score -1):

Try using the Toast class:

`Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: thanks,toast is also can achieve,but I hope know AlertDialog.Builder or Toast has show() method,but why not have hide() method ^^

Comment: `AlertDialog` does have a `cancel()` method, maybe you could use this with a timer to hide the dialog.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try Thread to show alert for some time....

private boolean mActive = true;
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT = 2000;

Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while (mActive && (waited < SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT)) {
                        sleep(70);

                        waited += 70;

                    }
//set Alert dialog here
                    AlertDialog.Builder.setMessage("OK").show();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
```

Comment: will not work because `show` must be called on the UI thread. Plus, it is the opposite to what is asked in the question